# send() function returning bad address error in client

Tags: c, sockets

Title is self-explanatory on what's happening, what's weird to me is no other function like `connect()`, `accept()`, and others are returning this.

Here is my full codes:

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>

#define PORT 8080 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

     int buffer[1024];
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
        { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
         } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 


    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
        { 
        perror("Invalid address \n"); 
        return -1; 
        } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
       { 
        perror("Connection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
        } 

      int i, array[argc], countsize;
     if(argc>=2){
     for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
       int number=atoi(argv[i]);
       array[i-1]=number;
       countsize++;
}

   if(send(sock, array, countsize*sizeof(int), 0)<0)
    {
    printf("Error in send! %s\n", strerror(errno));  //error is happening here
        return -1; 
    }
}
 return 0; 
}
```

Server:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include<errno.h>
#define PORT 8080 
int main() 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    int buffer;

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
        { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        } 


    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
        { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 


    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) 
        { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
        { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
        { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        } 

int arguments[10]={0};
int n = recv(new_socket, arguments ,1024*sizeof(int),0);

puts("The client sent the arguments: ");
int j;

for(j=0; j<n/sizeof(int);j++){
   printf("%d", arguments[j]);
   puts(".");
}
    return 0; 
}
```

I tried using `write()` as well as I am more familiar with its syntax (even though I double checked the syntax for `send()` and it returned the same error, any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: The problem likely has to do with `countsize`. You're not getting any warnings about it? (Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` if using gcc or clang)

Comment: I am using clang and I didn't get any warnings. I fixed it now, turns out it was just because of not initializing `countsize` which I didn't notice. 
Thanks a lot for this, I didn't know about `-Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
 int i, array[argc], countsize;
 if(argc>=2){
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
       int number=atoi(argv[i]);
       array[i-1]=number;
       countsize++;
    }
```

`countsize` is not initialized, meaning its value is **indeterminate**.  You then attempt to increment it before assigning any value to it.  Reading a variable with an indeterminate value that never had its address taken invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You want to initialize this variable to 0 so you start counting from a known point.

```
 int i, array[argc], countsize = 0;
```